# How do you make a 2d array from a text file in python and traverse it to get an average of the floats?

Tags: python, arrays, 2d

I have to get input from a text file of a sector and all of it's sales, it has to be stored in a 2d array has to be able to write an average function for data

> I tried it in java but I want to know how in python.

Comment: Welcome to the SO. You're expected to share a reproducible sample of your data and expected output so that others can help you.

Comment: Hi, we cannot help with general questions like this but we can help with specific programming questions, check out this link on how to ask a good question on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the Pandas library in Python. It has several handy functions for example creating a DataFrame (a 2D array which allows all sorts of manipulations and calculations).
You can install it using PIP in your CMD with the following command:

```
python3 -m pip install pandas
```

Your code should look something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Which pandas function you use depends on the file type you're working with
df = pd.read_excel("sector_data.xlsx")

# If there's a dividends column in your data, the following would calculate the mean.
dividend_mean = df["Dividends"].mean()
```

I suggest looking at some info about Pandas. It's a strong library.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html